# How to convert the Input field into select options?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any method of converting `input type="text"` tag convert into select options? Means that in the below snippet there is a input field which containing some value but is there any method that on click on this text field then it will convert into the select option. and when I choose any option from the select option then it will again change into the text field.(**This field is not the edit able field***)

```js
$("#textfield1").on("click",function(){
  $("#textfield1").html('<select id= "selct option"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>10</option></select>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder = "click on me" id="textfield1" value= "10">
```

Comment: if you are using any js framework like angular/reactjs, write some custom directives yourself. pass required input data and play around it

Comment: try http://selectric.js.org/demo.html

Comment: It is no different with using select only ! Why do you use input text if you want to show option when click >>> :(

Comment: Show/Hide input and select?

Comment: why using *un-editable* input to trigger a dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

You can not do because `input` and `select` both are different tags and attributes of both tag are also different.

```js
$("#textfield1").on("click",function(){
  $("#mainNode").html('<select id= "selct option"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>10</option></select>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainNode">
<input type="text" placeholder = "click on me" id="textfield1" value= "10">
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what would you like to do.

Here is an example for both side change.

If there's more information, I'll adjust my answer.

```js
$(document).on("click",'input',function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).replaceWith('<select id="selctoption"><option value="1">1</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="'+val+'" selected>'+val+'</option></select>');
  });
$(document).on("change",'select',function(){
  $(this).replaceWith('<input value="'+$(this).val()+'"/>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder = "click on me" id="textfield1" value= "10">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want to do as already mentioned the two tags are *very* different.

Here are a couple of options that might work for you.

**EDIT:** Fixed 2nd option

**Option 1**

Hard code in the select element then show and hide as required.

```js
//On Focus Of Texbox swap to select, this also caters for tabbing in
$("input[type='text'].hdnSelect").on("focus", function(){
  //hide this
  $(this).hide();
  
  //Show the next select
  $(this).next(".hdnSelect").show();
  
  //Set the correct value
   $(this).next(".hdnSelect").val($(this).val());
});

//Swap back on select or blur of select and set value
$("select.hdnSelect").on("blur change", function(){

  //Reset the value of the text box
  $(this).prev(".hdnSelect").val($(this).val());
  
  //Show The text box
  $(this).prev(".hdnSelect").show();
  
  //HIde this select
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
select.hdnSelect{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="10" id="txt1" class="hdnSelect">
  <select id="hdnSelect1" class="hdnSelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
    <input type="text" value="1" id="txt2" class="hdnSelect">
  <select id="hdnSelect2" class="hdnSelect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="10">Ten</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

**Option 2**

Use a data attribute to hold your element values and build dynamically from there

```js
//On Focus Of Texbox build select, this also caters for tabbing in
    $("input[type='text'].hdnSelect").on("focus", function(){
      //hide this
      $(this).hide();
      
      //Get raw options
      var opts = $(this).data("options").split(",");
      
      //Build Select
      var sel = document.createElement("select");
      var opt = "";
      
      opts.forEach(function(element){
        var kv = element.split("|");
        opt += "<option value='"+ kv[0] +"'>" + kv[1] + "</option>";
      });
      
      //Add Class and select value
      $(sel).html(opt).addClass("hdnSelect").val($(this).val());     
      
      
      //Insert the element
      $(this).after(sel);
      
    });

    //Swap back on select or blur of select and set value
    //As the element is now dynamically add we nee to change the on event
    $("form").on("blur change", "select.hdnSelect", function(){

      //Reset the value of the text box
      $(this).prev(".hdnSelect").val($(this).val());
      
      //Show The text box
      $(this).prev(".hdnSelect").show();
      
      //Remove this select
      try{
        //Removing triggers the blur event to fire again
        //Remove in try block to suppress the error on 2nd remove
        $(this).remove();
      }
      catch{}
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" value="10" id="txt1" class="hdnSelect" data-options="1|One,2|Two,10|Ten">
  
  <br><br>
    <input type="text" value="1" id="txt2" class="hdnSelect" data-options="1|One,2|Two,4|Four,10|Ten">  

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceWith()` for this. check updated snippet below...

```js
$("#textfield1").on("click",function(){
  $("#textfield1").replaceWith('<select id= "selct option"><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>10</option></select>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder = "click on me" id="textfield1" value= "10">
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add **options** from **textbox** for the already existing **select** element?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vignz_pie/e6w1qpuL/24/)

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>   
        function addOption() {
        val = $("#_textVal").val();
        key = $("#_textVal").val();
        if(val == ""){
            alert("Insert Text");
          return -1;
        }
        o = new Option(key, val);
        $("#_sel").append(o);
        $('#_textVal').val("");   }

      function editOption(sel) {
        val = sel.value;
        $('#_textVal').val(val);   }

    </script>
    <input type="text" placeholder="click on me" id="_textVal" value="10">
    <button id="_btnSet" onclick="addOption();">Set Option</button>

    <select id="_sel" onchange="editOption(this);"> </select>
```